# Ionic3/Angular4 iOS double tap

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I can't seem to get passed the double tap issue on iOS.  I want my app to respond to single click only.
I've added "tappable" to virtually all elements and I've removed and re-added the iOS platform.  I have been building production releases using the Ionic Cloud.  On Android all works perfectly.
I see this consistently happening on the popovers (i.e. hitting an ion-list element), the OK/Cancel buttons do not work with a single click, but the elements within the popover are selectable with a single click.

I feel like I'm not doing something right, since I've researched this for weeks and implemented all suggestions.

Is there anyone who successfully fixed this issue?
What would be the advice at this point, as I need to fix this for my production build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I discovered was that there was a jQuery or jQuery UI conflict.  Because my app had a custom design, I copied the  contents from the responsive web version and plugged it into the /src/index.html file.
I left my style link references, but I pulled out all JavaScript reference files (i.e. jquery, jqueryui) that are not required in an Ionic app.
The app no longer requires a double-tap on iOS for ion-select items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your html template :

```
(dblclick)="myFunction()"
```

and then in your .ts file :

```
myFunction(){
   //do things
}
```

Comment: Isn't this to call an event upon double-clicking?  My problem, is that I don't want the user to double-click.  Double-click always works.  I updated the original issue so that it is more clear what my issue is.  Thanks!